ITaskScheduler::NewWorkItem returns E_ACCESSDENIED while attempting to create task under same name
According to the Microsoft docs, the error code ERROR_FILE_EXISTS should be returned when attempting to create a task that already exists. However, when I run the sample program to create a task more than once, I receive the error code E_ACCESSDENIED instead.
Based on my understanding, if I delete the .job file that was created, the error does not occur.
So why the API returns E_ACCESSDENIED rather than ERROR_FILE_EXISTS?

probably you second time run your code not as admin. and got E_ACCESSDENIED. and you will got this code with any name. if you run as admin you will got HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_FILE_EXISTS)

"So why the API returns E_ACCESSDENIED rather than ERROR_FILE_EXISTS?" - Because that is the most specific reason why the API failed. This could be because it attempted to read, modify, or delete the file system object without sufficient permissions. Or it could be due to an attempt to list the directory contents without sufficient permissions.
